# How do I convert an NSInteger to an NSTimeInterval

Tags: cocoa, nstimeinterval

how to convert `NSInteger` to `NSTimeInterval`?

Answer (score 9):

NSInteger is normally defined as an int or long. NSTimeInterval is a plain double, so you can just assign one value to another.

Comment: Is it the same for converting `NSTimeInterval` to `NSInteger`? Instead of truncating though, I want to round. Should I just use `round(secs)`?