# How can I convert a NSInteger to a NSTimeInterval

Tags: iphone, nstimeinterval

I have `slideTimer` which is a `NSInteger` and I want to convert it to `NSTimeInterval`.

I tried like this:

```
 NSTimeInterval slider = (NSTimeInterval)slideTimer;
```

but it is not working.Any idea?

Comment: NSTimeIntervals are double values, b.t.w.  How is it not working?  If slideTimer is set to 10, do you only see slider as 0 after the assignment?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316570/how-do-i-convert-an-nsinteger-to-an-nstimeinterval

Answer (score 8):

NSTimeInterval is just:

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

This code:

```
int i = 1500;
NSTimeInterval interval = i;
NSLog(@"%d", (int)interval);
```

Outputs:

```
2011-11-07 07:47:05.579 Craplet[7608:707] 1500
```

BTW, in XCode 4.2, hold down control and apple keys and types will have underlines.  Click on that and you'll see the definition.

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift**:

```
let x: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(Int(123))
```